# my fetched data disappeared after I refreshed the Browser

Tags: reactjs

After using useState hook, it fetches data from Elasticsearch database and displays it on the browser, but when I refresh the browser, it gives an error. How can I remove the error?
the error message is :

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hits')"

N.B hits is my variable in Elasticsearch

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import './pages/table.css'

function JsonDataDisplay() {
    
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
  
    const apiGet = () => {
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpydHoxMDRpWGtjcV85RjZUTCtMMA==");

        var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
        };

        const ur = 'https://192.168.1.3:9200/myapp/_doc/1'
        const ur1 = 'https://192.168.1.3:9200/clientesafewindows-logstash/_search'

        fetch(ur1, requestOptions)   //https://192.168.1.3:9200/clientesafewindows-logstash/_search
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            
            setData(result);

            console.log(result._id);
            console.log(result);
            // console.log(date);

        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    };

    
    // This used to call the function on page load 
            useEffect(() => {
                apiGet();
            }, []);



                        // Return for URL 1
    return (
        <div>
             {/* This uded to call the function on page load without pressing a button */}
            {/* <button onClick={apiGet}>Fetch API</button> */}
        <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
            <tr>
                
                {/* <-- Url 1 --> */}
                {/* <th>ID</th>
                <th>Ignored</th> */}
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Score</th>

                {/* Agent */}
                <th>Ephemeral_id</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Version</th>

                {/* Event */}
                <th>Original</th>

                {/* Host */}
                <th>Architecture</th>
                <th>Hostname</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>IP</th>
                <th>MAC</th>
                <th>Name</th>

                {/* OS */}
                <th>Build</th>
                <th>Family</th>
                <th>Kernel</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Version</th>

                {/* Input */}
                <th>Type</th>

                <th>Message</th>

                {/* Shards */}
                <th>Failed</th>
                <th>Skipped</th>
                <th>Success</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                
            </tr>
                </thead>

            <tbody>

             <tr>
            {/* <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(myFunction(), null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(myFunction(), null, 2)}</pre></td> */}
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._index, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._score, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.agent.ephemeral_id, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.agent.id, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.agent.name)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.agent.type, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.agent.version, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.event.original)}</pre></td>
            
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.architecture, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.hostname, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.id)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.ip[7], null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.mac, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.name, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.os.build, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.os.family)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.os.kernel, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.os.name, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.os.platform, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.os.type)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.host.os.version, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.input.type, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits[1]._source.message, null, 2)}</pre></td>

            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data._shards.failed, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data._shards.skipped, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data._shards.successful)}</pre></td>
            <td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data._shards.total, null, 2)}</pre></td>
            
              </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        </div>
    );

}

export default JsonDataDisplay;
```

Comment: Please guys help me as soon as you can! please for God's  sake

Answer (score 0):

You're initial state is set to an array `[]` but it appears to be an `{}`

To prevent the errors you could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
<td><pre>{JSON.stringify(data.hits?.hits[1]._index, null, 2)}</pre></td>
```